# Why does Excel.Application.InputBox leaves an hidden Excel process?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, process

I am working on an Access database and I write a macro for it.
I try to obtain cell references using an Excel.InputBox.Application, but sometimes, when I execute the following code, it leaves an hidden running Excel process.
How can I avoid this? Does anyone have an idea? Thank you in advance.

I have already tried to write XLApp.Visible = False before XLApp.Quit.

```
Function TakesCellReference(Nom As String)
    Dim XLApp As Object
    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Set XLApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set xlBook = XLApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=Nom, UpdateLinks:=3, ReadOnly:=False)
    XLApp.Visible = True
    Set cellule = XLApp.InputBox(Prompt:="Sélectionnez une cellule de la feuille et cliquez sur Ok pour continuer", Type:=8)
    TakesCellReference = cellule.Address
    Set cellule = Nothing
    xlBook.Close False
    XLApp.Quit
    Set xlBook = Nothing
    Set XLApp = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare `cellule` inside your function.

Make sure to have [`Option Explicit`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) at the top of each module.
It enforces variable declaration and reports undeclared or misspelled variables/constants at compile time.
To have this automatically in new modules, set the [Require Variable Declaration](http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/modules/options/index.html) option in the VBA Editor.

The Excel process *probably* stays running because of a wrong order of cleanup calls. When you quit Excel, the reference to `xlBook` is still active and prevents the process from closing.

```
xlBook.Close False
XLApp.Quit
Set xlBook = Nothing
```

should be:

```
xlBook.Close False
Set xlBook = Nothing
XLApp.Quit
```

Comment: Thank you @Andre for your answer! I had tried all thoose things too but it hadn't worked. Sorry for being not accurate enough. I eventually found the reason why I had this process. I think it was created by an add-ins : "eformity Document Builder Microsoft Office Add-in" which I disabled manually. I was Lucky to find an other post about that this Morning.

Comment: Still make sure to use Option Explicit. :) @AMDRDB

Comment: Thanks again @Andre! I hadn't written it in this module actually. I did it yersterday and it prooved to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually found the reason why I had this hidden Excel process. I think it was created by an add-in : "eformity Document Builder Microsoft Office Add-in" which I disabled manually. I was Lucky to find another post about that this morning. I have executed my code about 20 times and I don't have any hidden Excel process anymore.

In case it could help someone, here is the way I disabled the add-ins. I went into Excel (not into Access), then in file, Options, Add-ins, I clicked on Go after having selected COM Add-ins. And I unticked "eformity Document Builder Microsoft Office Add-in".
I think we can do it with a vba code from access :

```
Sub UntickAddIns()
For i = 1 To Excel.Application.COMAddIns.Count
If Excel.Application.COMAddIns.Item(i).Description = "eformity Document Builder Microsoft Office Add-in" Then
Excel.Application.COMAddIns.Item(i).Connect = False
End If
Next
End Sub
```

I tried it and the only problem I had was that I didn't have the permission to change `Excel.Application.COMAddIns.Item(i).Connect` into `False`. I Don't know the solution yet but I don't think that's difficult.